# Is this the elided form of "the way I wrote it is that I wrote very correctly."

Tags: ellipses

> The way I wrote it, I wrote it very correctly.

Is it the elided form of this sentence below?

> The way I wrote it is that I wrote it very correctly.

I am not a native speaker, so I have to add that second sentence sounds a little off to my ear, but not entirely.

Comment: Hm..............anyone?

Comment: The trouble with the first variant is that 'The way I wrote it,' would normally be expected to be a shorter form of 'Considering the way I wrote it,' or 'I wrote it in such a way that ...'. 'The way I wrote it, a child of four could understand it.' // The second variant might be better with a 'was'; grammatical but _very_ stodgy and unidiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Something is either correct or incorrect; 'very' doesn't add anything substantial to this phrase.
This could be shortened to "I wrote it in the correct format/fashion/style/mode" (choose the word most appropriate for the context).

Answer (score 0):

To elide is to omit sounds or syllables, not whole words, but I take it you mean it that way. In that case, your sentence does omit a few words, so the answer to your question is yes.

The elimination of those words makes it no less redundant, though, which is why both of them sound "off," as you say. Just say:

> "I wrote it very correctly."

Comment: You're choosing one meaning for 'elide'. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elide) includes the broad definition 'to leave out of consideration :  omit'.